How to get display to show a pdf properly
When I do:
display file.pdf

it shows this:

I can't resize the little window that it adds but I can remove it by clicking on the x. I can also remove the checkerboard effect that comes from assuming transparency, I think, with:
display -alpha opaque file.pdf


The text is now rough and slightly hard to read. It seems to have been rendered in black and white where anti-aliasing should have used more shades/colors.
How can this be fixed?

Is there a reason you're using display? There are much better PDF viewers available.

@marcelm It was the only thing I found to view pdfs  on a particular server

You need to remove the alpha channel, rather than making it opaque — this will render the alpha information correctly (including anti-aliasing), then remove it.
display -alpha remove file.pdf

The small window shown above the main window is used to scroll around the document.

"  -alpha option        on, activate, off, deactivate, set, opaque, copy
transparent, extract, background, or shape" doesn't include remove interestingly.  That is what display -h gives you. How did you find the remove option?

It’s described in the manual, I’ve added a link in the answer.
